# Explain to me exactly what last_insert_id(expr) does

Tags: mysql

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
    `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `mimetype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `uploaded` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `filename` (`filename`,`hash`)
)
```

Let's say I insert something with filename "myFile" and hash "abc". Let's say it's not a duplicate and its id is 45.

Then let's say I insert some more queries so that the auto_increment index is higher now. For the sake of this example we'll say it's 70.

Now what happens when I do this:

```
insert into files(filename, hash, ...) values ("myFile", "abc", ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

What actually happens? Will it update the id of the file I am currently inserting to be 45? Or will it change the ID of the existing row to be 70? In the case of the former does that mean the old row is written over? In the case of the latter how does it know to use 45?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither (filename, hash) does not match, the IODKU statement will act like

```
insert into files(filename, hash, ...) values ("myFile", "abc", ...)`
```

And your subsequent `SELECT last_insert_id` will get the new id.

Else it will do a mostly no-op UPDATE.  Your `SET` contains only `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)`, which does *not* change id.  However, it does capture the existing value of `id` (45) so that your subsequent `SELECT last_insert_id` will get that value.

So, either way, you get the id of the row, whether it was INSERTed or UPDATEd.

(Yeah, the syntax is kinda kludgy.)